# max over c++ array with function call

Tags: c++

I have a list of `obj` objects which each have an `eval()` method, returning a `double`. I'd like to get the maximum value of all of these. So far, I've always done

```cpp
double maxval = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
for (const auto &obj: objs) {
  maxval = std::max(maxval, obj->eval());
}
```

I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution where you don't have to set the initial value -inf, something like Python's

```py
max_value = max(obj.eval() for obj in objs)
```

perhaps. Note than `eval()` may be expensive, so I only want to `eval()` once per `obj`.

Any hints? Bonus points for readability.

Comment: So the usual practice to use the value of the first one you visit is not an option for you? Why?

Comment: @Yunnosch The list may be empty.

Answer (score 4):

Some `<ranges>` nice things (C++20 only):

```
#include <ranges>

const auto maxval = std::ranges::max_element(objs, std::less<>{}, &ObjType::eval);

if (maxval != objs.cend())
    doStuffWith(*maxval);
```

where `ObjType` is the type of the sequence elements. The last check could also be on the size of the container as `maxval` would certainly be a dereferencable iterator when the sequence isn't empty, e.g.

```
if (!objs.empty()) ; // ...
```

Note however that as @NathanOliver has pointed out, this invokes `eval()` 2N-2 times. Here is a custom template that would call `eval()` exactly N times:

```
#include <optional>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <class Range, class Cmp = std::less<>, class Proj = std::identity>
auto maxValue(const Range& rng, Cmp pred = Cmp{}, Proj p = Proj{})
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    using ValueType = std::remove_cvref_t<std::invoke_result_t<Proj,
        decltype(*begin(rng))>>;

    auto first = begin(rng);
    const auto last = end(rng);

    if (first == last)
        return std::optional<ValueType>{};

    auto result = std::invoke(p, *first);

    for (++first; first != last; ++first)
        result = std::max(std::invoke(p, *first), result, pred);

    return std::optional{result};
}
```

It doesn't return an iterator, but the resulting value - wrapped into a `std::optional` in case the range is empty (then the result is `std::nullopt`). Usage for a type `Test` with member function `Test::eval()` would be like this:

```
const auto max = maxValue(myContainer, std::less<>{}, &Test::eval);
```

Second and third argument have sensible defaults, so for primitive types and the like they could be left out.

Comment: How often is `eval` called per `obj`?

Comment: It's a linear algorithm, so once per object.

Comment: Linear complexity could also mean k times per object, e.g., twice.

Comment: Wouldn't this still have two calls to `eval` per element?  ie, `e1 cmp e2` is called and then `e2 cmp e3` ... so only the first and last element get `cmp` called once on them.

Comment: Looks like it is called `2N-2` times: https://wandbox.org/permlink/e260qaoY4RnqjuGB

Answer (score 2):

The C++ equivalent to Python's `max` is [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element).

```
auto itr = std::max_element(
    objs.begin(), objs.end(),
    [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return lhs.eval() < rhs.eval(); }
);
if (itr != objs.end()) {
    double maxval = *itr;
}
```

Comment: Does this cache the results of `eval()`?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer I don't think caching is required by the standard, so it probably depends on the standard library implementation.

Comment: How should it cache the result?! There is no state involved here. It can't write the result into a global variable to return it upon the next invocation.

Comment: I see. It's an interesting solution then, but not too useful for me. `eval()` can be expensive, so I really only want to `eval()` once per object.